# Different detail levels in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax, dimensional-modeling

EDITED
I'm having a problem with a table, where I need to store measures on different detail levels. My default table is:

| Id | TotalQuantity | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75 | 1000 |

Where TotalQuantity is a sum of quantities from every month.

Now I need to add into my default table an information, what quantities I have each month. These monthly quantities should be in one column, so I used UNION.

The problem is that when I will sum up values from these columns in some reports, TotalQuantity AND OTHER VALUES THAT ARE THE SAME FOR BOTH ROWS will be displayed wrong. How can I possibly store all that information?

Comment: Your data model should get rid of `TotalQuantity` and just sum `QuantityByMonth`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I should probably update my question, cause the table contains other values that I dont want to sum up (not only TotalQuantity).

Comment: Are they 12 separate columns, or 12 separate rows? Please supply sample input data

Comment: I wanted to know what the input `table` looked like. Meaning does it have say 12 columns `month1`,`month2`,`month3`... (or is it just two columns?), or maybe you are calculating them by aggregation? What is the query that gets you to that first result, and what does the base `table` look like?

Comment: You should have this as separate rows, not columns, as @DavidBrowne says. Then you can sum up by using `GROUPING SETS` or `ROLLUP`, to get both a total for each year and individual months

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks! I'll try that out

Answer (score 2):

You need a fact table at the (id, month) grain, like `FactMonthlyTotals(id, month, amount)`.  If you have other data that is not for a particular month it would go on a separate fact table, or perhaps a dimension table.